# Scheduling PHP file cannot send email

Tags: php, email, scheduled-tasks

I have the following PHP file which is used to send a simple email, I have tried to open this php file by a browser, so to execute it, I can successfully receive the email. However, when I try to send it buy a window scheduler, I am not able to do so. The way I open the file in scheduler is C:/xampp/htdocs/mail.php, I have tried to check the log of Mercury, but no mail is received by Mercury, so probably mail.php is not being executed. May I ask why it cannot be scheduled to run?

Here is my mail.php:

```
<?php
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Mercury test mail', 'If you can read this, everything was fine!');
?>
```

[image: my schedule is running]

Taking the advice I have made changes, but still the email cannot be sent

[image]

Comment: check also if the scheduler runs the script with the correct rights... usually as administrator should do the trick.

Comment: You dont have header part in mail() .If you dont have proper headers there is no guarantee that you will receive your mail at your inbox . Gmail may drop the mail or put in spam box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are scheduling it incorrectly.

To use Windows Scheduler or to run a PHP file from a command line, you need to use the following format:

```
C:\path\to\your\php.exe -f 'C:\path\to\your\actual.php'
```

That should then run your script.

Additionally, you often configure the `php.ini` that the CLI uses to be different, so make sure that your settings for SMTP and the like are consistent between them.

Lastly, if you want to know what happens during your script, you can have them echo out text (so use things like `\n` for new lines etc, and output to a text file like this:

```
C:\path\to\your\php.exe -f 'C:\path\to\your\actual.php' > 'C:\path\to\where\you\want\logfile.txt'
```

Comment: so you mean I should type in the format you mentioned in the Program/script field? Then it can run successfully?

Comment: @user1502740 Yes, it looks like your scheduler isn't actually `executing` the php script properly - hence you never get the email. You are using Windows Scheduler for this yes? If so, change your schedule and test it by right clicking the schedule and choosing `Run Now` and it should work.

Comment: these all "-f 'C:\path\to\your\actual.php' > 'C:\path\to\where\you\want\logfile.txt' " should be in the argument field, right?

Comment: Also you can add an entry in ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES for `C:\path\to\your\` so that you can directly use `php phpscript.php` anywhere and not specifying `C:\path\to\your\php.exe phpscript.php` all the time

Comment: @user1502740 Argument Field? Just to confirm, you are using Windows Scheduler to kick these jobs off yes? If so, just enter that whole command into field labelled RUN.

Comment: yes, I am using Windows Scheduler, but I still cannot run my code even following your advice, I have no idea why, as shown above, my code is just in the same format as yours

Comment: @user1502740 The best way to test that you have all your paths right is to open up a Windows DOS Prompt (Start->Run>CMD) and make sure that you have the command properly using all the right folders to get to your files.

Comment: when I use cmd to execute the command, I first enter the directory C:\xampp\php and then type php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\Me\mail.php, the code can execute successfully, and the mail is in my mail box now, but when when I put the same command in task scheduler, it does not work?

Comment: Assuming that the data in your comment matches your actual files, try this command (from the C:\ folder - don't navigate anywhere else) `C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Me\mail.php'` and you should see it run and mail you. Then use that exact command in windows scheduler.

Comment: @user1502740 Excellent, can you please Accept the answer that way we can all move on please?

Answer (score 0):

Run a PHP file from Command Prompt.Try this Command

> "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Yourmailscript.php"